# How to filter a dict of list in python?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I have a blog app built by django, i want to notic the bloger if there is a new comment, so here is what i did

```
class Blog(models.Model):
     lastview = models.DateTimeField('self last view date')

class Comment(models.Model):
     blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField('comment date')

user_blog_list = Blog.Objects.filter(author = request.user)
user_blog_com = {}

for blog in user_blog_list:
      user_blog_com [blog] =list(Comment.objects.filter(blog = blog ))
```

now the `user_blog_com` is dict look like

```
{
  (Blog: blogname1):[(Comment:comment1),(Comment:comment2)],
  (Blog: blogname2):[(Comment:comment1),(Comment:comment2)],
}
```

next i need to compare each comment's timestamp with blog's lastview, to find out if the comment is viewed by the bloger,but I don't know how .

what I want is a disc like

```
{
  (Blog: blogname):[(Comment:unviewed_comment),(Comment:unviewed_comment)],
}
```

please help!!!

i try this

```
user_blog_com = {}

for blog in user_blog_list:
      user_blog_com [blog] =list(Comment.objects.filter(blog = blog ,timestamp > blog.lastview ))

 get an error: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you do that when querying for `Comment`s?

Comment: dicts have no order... you may want to look at ordereddict

Comment: u mean like  user_blog_com [blog] =list(Comment.objects.filter(blog = blog, timestamp > blog.lastview )) ?

Comment: @chenliang I believe you're approaching this problem from the wrong direction. You're doing a lot of roundabout processing that could be achieved with a single ORM query.

Comment: yes i did, and i get it work by : user_blog_com [blog] =list(Comment.objects.filter(blog = blog ,timestamp__ge =  blog.lastview ))

Comment: @chenliang no, that's what I mean. You're doing two queries there. There is no need to do any `Blog.objects` querying at all, because you're after `Comment`s. See my solution with `F() Expressions`

Comment: yes your answer is much more elegant thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but the following should give you a list of new comments for every blog.

```
from django.db.models import F

comments = Comment.objects.filter(
        blog__author=request.user
    ).filter(
        timestamp__gte=F('blog__lastview')
    ).select_related('blog').order_by('blog')
```

[F() Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.F) allow you to refer to values within the database on a row-by-row basis. Other than that, you're just asking for all new comments `timestamp__gte=blog__lastview`, where the current user was the author. We use `select_related` so you can access the details on the `blog` instance without another query, and `order_by('blog')` so that you've got some ordering.

If you HAVE to have this information in a dictionary (I wonder why this would be the case..) then you do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for comment in comments:
    d[comment.blog.name].append(comment)
```

Much more readable and expressive than the way you're trying to construct it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ret_dict = {}
for k, v in user_blog_com.items():
    # Check comments timestamp is smaller than lastview.
    ret_dict[k] = [x for x in v if x.timestamp <= k.lastview]

print ret_dict
```

This may help you.

Comment: Or: `ret_dict = {k:[x for x in v if x.timestamp <= k.lastview] for k, v in user_blog_com.items()}` in python 2.7+